# why jpg images can't be imported in vite for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I wanted to import a `.jpg` file to my React file but when I wanted to do that, an error popped up, so I don't have this problem with `.png` or `.svg` files, so I was wondering why this error pops up for `.jpg` files and how should we fix that?

error:

```
Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains 
invalid JS syntax. You may need         to install appropriate plugins 
to handle the .JPG file format, or if it's an asset, add "**/*.JPG" to       
`assetsInclude` in your configuration.
```

Comment: The message is telling you to add the JPG format to the `assetsInclude` config, do you have a config like `defineConfig`? https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude

Comment: so why is this happening even from the first place?@Harrison

Comment: It seems to be a deliberate decision from Vite to reduce the build size, but to still allow developers to include that functionality as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you're getting and [the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude), it looks like all you need to do is add `**/*.JPG` to the config like so:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.JPG'],
})
```